# problems with cloud front and S3 - Terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, terraform, amazon-cloudfront, amazon-route53

1. When i do **terraform apply** it's created all the resources but i got:

   ```
   Error: putting S3 Bucket (www.test.com) Policy: operation error S3: PutBucketPolicy, https response error StatusCode: 403, RequestID: *************** HostID: *******************************************=, api error AccessDenied: Access Denied
   ```

when i  do **terraform apply** again without any configuration changes it's deploy the policy...

1. i created A record and CNAME records for my domain but wheni try to launch the domain via browser i redirected to the cloudfront dns ( i tryed with chrome, edge also in cognito mode...)

**This is my S3 main.tf:**

```
resource "aws_s3_bucket" "test-website" {
bucket = "www.test.com"
}

resource "aws_s3_object" "test-website-objects-imagesANDpdf" {
bucket = aws_s3_bucket.test-website.id
for_each = fileset("../My Site/images/","**/*")
key = each.value
source = "../My Site/images/${each.value}"
}

resource "aws_s3_object" "test-website-objects-html" {
bucket = aws_s3_bucket.test-website.id
key = "index.html"
source = "../My Site/index.html"
content_type = "text/html"
}

resource "aws_s3_object" "test-website-objects-css" {
bucket = aws_s3_bucket.test-website.id
key = "style.css"
source = "../My Site/style.css"
content_type = "text/css"
}
resource "aws_s3_object" "test-website-objects-js" {
bucket = aws_s3_bucket.test-website.id
key = "script.js"
source = "../My Site/script.js"
}

resource "aws_s3_bucket_website_configuration" "test-website-configuration" {
    bucket = aws_s3_bucket.test-website.id
    index_document {
    suffix = "index.html"
    }
}

resource "aws_s3_bucket_public_access_block" "ReadOnly-All" {
  bucket = aws_s3_bucket.test-website.id
  block_public_acls       = false
  block_public_policy     = false
  ignore_public_acls      = false
  restrict_public_buckets = false
}
 resource "aws_s3_bucket_policy" "test-website-bucket-policy" {
  depends_on = [ aws_s3_bucket.test-website]
  bucket = aws_s3_bucket.test-website.id

  policy = <<EOF
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "PublicRead",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": "*",
      "Action": ["s3:GetObject"],
      "Resource": [
        "arn:aws:s3:::www.test.estcom/*"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
EOF

}
```

**This is my CloudFront main.tf:**

```
resource "aws_cloudfront_distribution" "test_com_cloudfront" {
  origin {
    domain_name              = var.aws_s3_bucket_bucket_domain_name
    origin_id                = var.aws_s3_bucket_bucket_domain_name 
  }

  enabled             = true
  is_ipv6_enabled     = true
  comment             = "www.test.com"
  default_root_object = "index.html"



  default_cache_behavior {
    allowed_methods  = ["DELETE", "GET", "HEAD", "OPTIONS", "PATCH", "POST", "PUT"]
    cached_methods   = ["GET", "HEAD"]
    target_origin_id = var.aws_s3_bucket_bucket_domain_name

    forwarded_values {
      query_string = false

      cookies {
        forward = "none"
      }
    }

    viewer_protocol_policy = "redirect-to-https"
    min_ttl                = 0
    default_ttl            = 3600
    max_ttl                = 86400
  }

aliases = [ "test.com" , "www.test.com" ]
  # Cache behavior with precedence 0
  ordered_cache_behavior {
    path_pattern     = "/content/immutable/*"
    allowed_methods  = ["GET", "HEAD", "OPTIONS"]
    cached_methods   = ["GET", "HEAD", "OPTIONS"]
    target_origin_id = var.aws_s3_bucket_bucket_domain_name

    forwarded_values {
      query_string = false
      headers      = ["Origin"]

      cookies {
        forward = "none"
      }
    }

    min_ttl                = 0
    default_ttl            = 86400
    max_ttl                = 31536000
    compress               = true
    viewer_protocol_policy = "redirect-to-https"
  }

  ordered_cache_behavior {
    path_pattern     = "/content/*"
    allowed_methods  = ["GET", "HEAD", "OPTIONS"]
    cached_methods   = ["GET", "HEAD"]
    target_origin_id = var.aws_s3_bucket_bucket_domain_name

    forwarded_values {
      query_string = false

      cookies {
        forward = "none"
      }
    }

    min_ttl                = 0
    default_ttl            = 3600
    max_ttl                = 86400
    compress               = true
    viewer_protocol_policy = "redirect-to-https"
  }

  restrictions {
    geo_restriction {
      restriction_type = "none"
    }
  }

  viewer_certificate {
    cloudfront_default_certificate = false
    acm_certificate_arn = var.test_com_acm_arn
    ssl_support_method = "sni-only"
    minimum_protocol_version = "TLSv1.2_2021"
  }
}
```

Comment: maybe `aws_s3_bucket_policy.test-website-bucket-policy` was applied before `aws_s3_bucket_public_access_block.ReadOnly-All`